# Unable to specify slide size when exporting a plot from R to a pptx file using R packages OFFICER and RVG

Tags: r, plot, powerpoint, officer

I have created a plot in R, and exported it as a vector object in a powerpoint slide (pptx file), using the "rvg" and "officer" packages (see code below).

I would like to define the dimensions (height and width) of the slides in the pptx create by the code, but I cannot see an option to do this. It is possible to specify the size of the plot object exported, but not the size of the powerpoint slide size.

**Is it possible to define the size of the powerpoint slide when exporting a plot from R into a pptx file?**

Many thanks for advice/help

```
#EXAMPLE CODE
#IMPORT LIBRARIES
library(officer)
library(rvg)
#MAKE RANDOM DATA
x<-rnorm(50,1,10)
y<-rnorm(50,2,20)
#WRAP PLOT CODE IN A FUNCTION
plot.code<-function(){
  plot(x,y)
}
#CREATE AND EXPORT PPTX FILE
export.plot<-read_pptx()
export.plot <- add_slide(export.plot, "Title and Content", "Office Theme")
export.plot<-ph_with_vg(export.plot,code=plot.code(),type="body",height=10,width=10)
 #height and width in the above code define the size of the plot, not the slide
print(export.plot, target = "export.plot.pptx")
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question, and haven't yet found a clear answer, but I did figure out a shoddy work-around.

1. Open Powerpoint and save an empty presentation with slides the size that you want.
2. In R, read in the powerpoint that you just created.
3. Add the content in R
4. Save powerpoint in R.

That will look something like this, with a *previously created* `manually_created.pptx`.

```
doc <- officer::read_pptx("manually_created.pptx") %>%
        # remove the empty slide
        officer::remove_slide(1)

doc %>% 
   # add a new slide to the powerpoint
   officer::add_slide("Title and Content", "Office Theme") %>% 
   # add plot to the slide
   officer::ph_with_vg(code = plot.code(), type = "body", height = 10, width = 10) %>%
   # save the powerpoint
   officer:::print.rpptx("manually_created.pptx")
```

Comment: I realize it might seem like excess work to remove a slide and then immediately add a slide, but this setup allows you to put the 2nd code chunk into a for loop to add a bunch of figures to individual slides. (If doing the for loop, I recommend moving the `print` statement outside of the loop so that it only runs once.)

Comment: `officer::ph_with_vg()` is no longer an `officer` function.  Probably use `ph_with()`